# Removing elements with Except

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Below I have a method that is supposed to delete all versions of a file except the newest. My `Except` call is not producing the result I'm expecting and after looking at the docs once again I can't seem to understand why. For the purpose of debugging I've moved the LINQ query with `Except` out of my foreach condition. When I debug `newest` is correctly set to the most recent log file, after the next line executes `toDelete` still contains `newest`, why? What am I missing here? All the relevant code is below. The method gets called passing with file set to the static part of the log name, after that it has a time stamp. Both `Where(x => x.Contains(file))` work exactly as I expect them to.

```
public static void CleanUpLocalCopies(string file)
{
    string[] localFiles = Directory.GetFiles(".\\");

    string newest = files.Where(x => x.Contains(file)).OrderByDescending(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
    var toDelete = localFiles.Where(x => x.Contains(file)).Except(new string[] { newest });

    foreach (string f in toDelete)
    {
        File.Delete(f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you can just use skip to skip the first file directly, and avoid the `Except` call:

```
var toDelete = files.Where(x => x.Contains(file)).OrderByDescending(x => x).Skip(1);
```

Comment: This works and is a better solution, because of that I will accept it. But, by chance could you explain why my `Except` isn't working?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal It's tough to tell - the code you posted doesn't actually compile as is, so I can't see exactly what's wrong with it ;)

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I tried it, replacing `files` with `localFiles` (it didn't compile), and it works correctly. If I have 3 files named 'abc' followed by timestamps, toDelete contains the 2 oldest.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault oh you just gave me my aha moment. `files` is a property on the class containing this method and it wasn't working because `files` is a list of the files on some FTP share while I was trying to delete local files... So the `Except` was working correctly, just on the wrong set.